# Selenium:Get the text on a section class if only if is available

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

need some help again, I got stuck again in a code I'm building.

The complexity here... not for all the HTMLs I will use here have the section available...

> <section class="pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-phone>

```xml
<section class="pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-phone">
    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="phone-handset" class="pv-contact-info__contact-icon">
        <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
            <path d="M21.7 19.18l-1.92 1.92a3.07 3.07 0 01-3.33.67 25.52 25.52 0 01-8.59-5.63 25.52 25.52 0 01-5.63-8.59 3.07 3.07 0 01.67-3.33L4.82 2.3a1 1 0 011.41 0l3.15 3.11A1.1 1.1 0 019.41 7L7.59 8.73a20.51 20.51 0 007.68 7.68l1.78-1.79a1.1 1.1 0 011.54 0l3.11 3.11a1 1 0 010 1.41z"></path>
        </svg>
    </li-icon>
    <h3 class="pv-contact-info__header t-16 t-black t-bold">
            Phone
          </h3>
    <ul class="list-style-none">
        <li class="pv-contact-info__ci-container t-14">
            <span class="t-14 t-black t-normal">
                  +391234567891
                </span>
            <span class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
                    (Mobile)
                  </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

So Im trying to add a condition for it, like if the section doesn't exist, so write no *Phone numb not available for this provider*

This is the code I have done for it

```py
try:
    phone_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-phone']//span[@class='t-14 t-black t-normal']")))
    phone = phone_element.get_attribute("innerHTML").strip()

except NoSuchElementException:
    phone = "Phone numb not available for this provider"
```

I am saving that variable into a CSV file.

But I'm getting the following exception when I run the code.

> phone_element = WebDriverWait(driver,
> 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
> "//section[@class='pv-contact-info__contact-type
> ci-phone']//span[@class='t-14 t-black t-normal']")))   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py",
> line 95, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

Everything was working finer until I added that condition to the code.

Comment: looks like you are catching a `NoSuchElementException` and the exception is `TimeoutException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the HTML:

```
<section class="pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-phone">
    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="phone-handset" class="pv-contact-info__contact-icon">
    <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-supported-dps="24x24" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="24" height="24" focusable="false">
        <path d="M21.7 19.18l-1.92 1.92a3.07 3.07 0 01-3.33.67 25.52 25.52 0 01-8.59-5.63 25.52 25.52 0 01-5.63-8.59 3.07 3.07 0 01.67-3.33L4.82 2.3a1 1 0 011.41 0l3.15 3.11A1.1 1.1 0 019.41 7L7.59 8.73a20.51 20.51 0 007.68 7.68l1.78-1.79a1.1 1.1 0 011.54 0l3.11 3.11a1 1 0 010 1.41z"></path>
    </svg>
    </li-icon>
    <h3 class="pv-contact-info__header t-16 t-black t-bold">
        Phone
    </h3>
    <ul class="list-style-none">
    <li class="pv-contact-info__ci-container t-14">
        <span class="t-14 t-black t-normal">
          +391234567891
        </span>
        <span class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
            (Mobile)
          </span>
    </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

To extract the text incase the `<section>` is available, instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  try:
      phone_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-phone']//h3[contains(., 'Phone')]//following-sibling::ul[1]//li/span")))
      phone = phone_element.get_attribute("innerHTML").strip()
      print(phone)

  except TimeoutException:
          print("Phone numb not available for this provider")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)