# Selenium with Python - Test failing in a line of code that worked for 170 previous tests

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I have a very strange behaviour happening while automating a test suite were I access a website, click on a search bar and then look for certain information.

All my 200+ tests begin the same way with the exact same code and the first 177 pass perfectly but from test 178 and onwards it fails in the line of code where i find the search bar and then click on it.

To me this makes no sense but again, I´m quite new to automation and IT in general so I hope you people can give me a hand here.

The line that fails is the following one:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((coupons_search_bar))).click()
```

Again, this works for 177 tests straight and then it fails in the following ones.

Thanks!

I changed the way I get to the coupons search bar in many ways but they work for the 177 first tests but fail for the following ones.

I cleaned the local storage and cache and nothing changed.

Comment: In these scenarios, it's invaluable to watch the execution of the test to actually see what's happening.  that's where services like BrowserStack or SauceLabs are helpful because you get a recording.  Alternatively, set up your test execution to capture a screenshot of the browser at the point that it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally to locate and click on the **clickable** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Line of code:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((coupons_search_bar))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

Without additional debugging details, there are different reasons why your script may start failing after X number of times. Here are some common ones:

- Too many requests on the same website raised a pop-up. In which case you would see an `ElementClickInterceptedException` (`other element would receive the click`) until you close the pop-up first.
- Too many requests on the same website triggered anti-bot measures. (Because some sites don't want to be automated.) Maybe do some rate-limiting on your requests.
- Other elements appeared, changing timing. Swap `EC.presence_of_element_located` with `element_to_be_clickable`.
- The website is doing A/B testing, which means another version of the site appeared. In that scenario, add in an `if` statement to change your script depending on what's visible.

Please edit your question with more relevant info, such as adding exception messages, the selector used, and any other details that may help with debugging if none of the above ideas helped.