# Accept Oracle.com privacy banner using Selenium with python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm trying to to automate clicking on the accept button on the privcy banner on Oracle.com but selenium either cannot find the button or it just does nothing.
unfortuntly the banner will always appear so I cannot click it manually for once.

The elemen is only defined by class but not sure what I'm doing wrong

```py
acceptCookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'call')))

acceptCookies.click()
```

##### also tried

```py
    cookies = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pdynamicbutton')
    acceptCookies = cookies.find_element(By,CLASS_NAME, "call")
    
    acceptCookies.click()
```

Here is a screen shot of the dev option on firefox
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, for some reason StackOverflow only accepted this and was rejecting correctly formatted code

Answer (score 0):

The element <kbd>Accept all</kbd> within the [Oracle Homepage](https://www.oracle.com/) is within an `<a>` tag.

```
<a class="call" tabindex="0">Accept all</a>
```

---

### Solution

To click on the ***clickable*** element instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Accept all"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pdynamicbutton a.call"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pdynamicbutton']//a[@class='call' and text()='Accept all']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the three options worked, it looks like selenium is not seeing that pop up at all. the three will fail with exactly the same errors the element cannot be found example of the error: `code` selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:187:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:505:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:135:16

Comment: I think that the cookies pop up is just an overlay so I think there should be some method to switch to it, can someone with good experiences try to replicate my situation?

Comment: Send me the details please.