# Find element by XPath sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Given the following slightly pseudo code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome

options = ChromeOptions()
driver = Chrome(options=options)

waiter = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
list_of_urls = [<list_of_urls>]

for url in list_of_urls:
    locator = (By.XPATH, "xpath_element_A")
    element_A_condition = expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(locator)
    element_A = waiter.until(element_A_condition)

    try:
        locator = (By.XPATH, "xpath_sub_element_A")
        sub_element_A_condition = expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(locator)
        sub_element_A = waiter.until(sub_element_A_condition)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        raise e
```

I'm finding that about 2-3% of the URLs I try to scrape are raising the `TimeoutException`.

I've tried extending the wait time and I've even tried refreshing the page multiple times and attempting the entire page-scrape again - all to no avail.

To try and get to the bottom of this I put a breakpoint on the final line and ran the code in debugging mode. When the exception was raised and the break point hit I ran `waiter.until(sub_element_A_condition)` again in the debug terminal and it immediately returned `sub_element_A`.

I've now repeated this debugging process multiple times and the result is always the same - the `TimeoutException` is raised and the break point hit but I'm able to immediately run `waiter.until(sub_element_A_condition)` and it always returns the element.

This is most perplexing. The only thing I think I've done differently when the exceptions were raised was that I switched to the window (I run non-headless) to manually eyeball that the element was on the page. Could that be doing something that causes the element to become visible?

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to ***scrape***, instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and your modified code block will be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome

options = ChromeOptions()
driver = Chrome(options=options)

waiter = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
list_of_urls = [<list_of_urls>]

for url in list_of_urls:
    locator = (By.XPATH, "xpath_element_A")
    element_A_condition = expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(locator)
    element_A = waiter.until(element_A_condition)

    try:
        locator = (By.XPATH, "xpath_sub_element_A")
        sub_element_A_condition = expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(locator)
        sub_element_A = waiter.until(sub_element_A_condition)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        raise e
```

---

In a single line:

```
element_A = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath_element_A")))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've implemented what you suggest and so far so good. However, it takes a while for the rest of the application to generate the URLs so it might be a couple of days before I can conclusively say it fixed things! If all good then I will be back to hit that tick :)

Comment: Hi. Afraid I'm still triggering the same `TimeoutException` :(

Answer (score 0):

you should add waits, try use contains in your xpath instead