# Unable to find element button on my selenium python code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to find out following "new request" button from the html page(mentioned below to button tag)

```
<button class="as-main-button definitely-not-a-aff-button" onclick="window.location.href='/FireFlow/SelfService/ChooseTemplate.html?Queue=1';">+ &nbsp;New Request</button>
```

Following is the code I tried but after so many tries still not able to find out that the desired button, still not sure why that button is not visible to the code, following is the code:

```
try:
    button_class_name = "button.as-main-button.definitely-not-a-aff-button"
    element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, button_class_name)))
    logging.info("New Request element is visible")

    time.sleep(5)
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"Failed to create new request : {e}")
```

And I got following error all the time:

```
2023-08-10 01:34:45,850 - ERROR - Failed to create new request : Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003EA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x0037C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00285358]
    (No symbol) [0x002B09A5]
    (No symbol) [0x002B0B3B]
    (No symbol) [0x002DE232]
    (No symbol) [0x002CA784]
    (No symbol) [0x002DC922]
    (No symbol) [0x002CA536]
    (No symbol) [0x002A82DC]
    (No symbol) [0x002A93DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0064AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0068A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0068456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x004751E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00385F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00382328]
    (No symbol) [0x0038240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00374FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75AA7D59+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7761B79B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x7761B71F+191]
```

This is my web page I look into (not the entire page):

https://gist.github.com/indrajeetgour/a54b8f2f89aaafe6160cb8bfe189ff66

Do let me know if something more required for this problem to solve.
Just to mentioned I am new to the selenium. Please help me out.

Update1: I forgot to mentioned that, I got into this page from another page, do you guys see should I switch the driver first before searching for any element in the new page(as mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

Given the html:

```
<button class="as-main-button definitely-not-a-aff-button" onclick="window.location.href='/FireFlow/SelfService/ChooseTemplate.html?Queue=1';">+ &nbsp;New Request</button>
```

To identify the element with text ***+ New Request*** instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.as-main-button.definitely-not-a-aff-button[onclick^='window.location.href']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button['as-main-button definitely-not-a-aff-button' and contains(., 'New Request')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I added some more context to the question as update1. 

As still I could not find the right element as suggested, do you think should I change anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

This css selector is working for me: `"#actionsPanel button"`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding, I added some more context to the question as update1. 

As still I could not find the right element as you suggest, do you think should I change anything to  the code.