# Unable to get an element using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been unable to get the rating number from the website https://www.hoka.com/en/us/mens-everyday-running-shoes/rincon-3/1119395.html using selenium.

This is what I have as Python code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    url = "https://www.hoka.com/en/us/mens-everyday-running-shoes/rincon-3/1119395.html"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    res = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'h3')
    for i in res:
        print(i.text)
```

I am getting empty result.

Here's the line with the info I want to extract:

[image: Here's the line with the info I want to extract]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To print the text ***4.4*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://www.hoka.com/en/us/mens-everyday-running-shoes/rincon-3/1119395.html')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.pr-review-snapshot-snippets-headline"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://www.hoka.com/en/us/mens-everyday-running-shoes/rincon-3/1119395.html')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[starts-with(@class, 'pr-review-snapshot-snippets-headline')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  4.4
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use unique locator to match particular element.

If `text` method doesn't work properly, it's possible to get it via `get_attribute('innerText')`

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

#previous code

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
rating = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.pr-review-snapshot-snippets h3')))

print(rating.get_attribute('innerText'))
```