# How to scrape data from webpage which uses react.js with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am facing some difficulties scraping a website which uses `react.js` and not sure why this is happening.

This is the html of the website:
[image]

What I wish to do is click on the button with the `class: play-pause-button btn btn -naked`. However, when I load the page with the Mozilla gecko webdriver there is an exception thrown saying

```
Message: Unable to locate element: .play-pause-button btn btn-naked
```

which makes me think that maybe I should do something else to get this element? 
This is my code so far:

```
driver.get("https://drawittoknowit.com/course/neurological-system/anatomy/peripheral-nervous-system/1332/brachial-plexus---essentials")
    # execute script to scroll down the page
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    time.sleep(10)        
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    print(driver.page_source)
    play_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("play-pause-button btn btn-naked").click()
    print(play_button)
```

Does anyone have an idea as to how I could go about solving this? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were close. While using `find_element_by_class_name()` you **can't** pass multiple *classes* and you are allowed to pass only one *classname*, i.e. only only one among either of the following:

- `play-pause-button`
- `btn`
- `btn-naked`

On passing multiple classes through `find_element_by_class_name()` you will face [Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-using-find-element-by-class/53536022#53536022)

---

### Solution

As an alternative, as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.play-pause-button.btn.btn-naked")))click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='play-pause-button btn btn-naked']")))click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```