# Scrape data after clicking on two buttons

Tags: javascript, html, vba, click, href

I'm trying to scrape the href of each model from this webpage: https://www.aprilia.com/en_EN/index.
The html showing the href data can be seen only after clicking on two buttons (the one on the top right corner and the one on the left called "Models"), one after the other.

```vb
Sub get_info()
  
Dim ie As Object
Dim address, str_chk As String
Dim my_data As Object
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim i As Long
  
address = "https://www.aprilia.com/en_EN/index"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate address 'the one mentioned above
ie.Visible = False
  
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
  
For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByName("button")
    If oHTML_Element.className = "header__menu-services__nav button button--icon" Then
        oHTML_Element.Click
    End If
Next
  
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#

For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByName("Models")
    oHTML_Element.Click
Next

Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#

'==>
Set my_data = html.getElementsByClassName("card-product card-product--family")

For Each elem In my_data
    For i = 0 To elem.getElementsByTagName("a").Length - 1
        str_chk = elem.getElementsByTagName("a")(i).href
        ws.Cells(9 + j, 7).Value = str_chk
        j = j + 1
    Next i
Next elem

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

I got

> Error '424' - Object Required

where I set `my_data`.

I guess that means that I'm not able to click on the two buttons and, as a consequence, html code is not available.

***************** Revised code:

```vb
Sub get_info22()

Dim address As String
Dim ie, ELE, nodes As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim t As Date
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
  
address = "https://www.aprilia.com/en_EN/index"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate address 'the one mentioned above
ie.Visible = False
  
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'************** click on first button
t = Timer
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ELE = ie.document.querySelector(".header__menu-services__nav")

    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
Loop While ELE Is Nothing
If Not ELE Is Nothing Then
    ELE.Click
End If

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
'************** click on second button
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ELE = ie.document.querySelector("li > button")

    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
Loop While ELE Is Nothing

If Not ELE Is Nothing Then
    ELE.Click
End If

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

'************** get href for each model

Set nodes = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".card-product--family")

ReDim hrefs(nodes.Length - 1)

For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
    hrefs(i) = nodes.Item(i).href
    ActiveSheet.Cells(9 + i, 7).Value = hrefs(i)
Next
```

Comment: You've not declared or populated a variable named `html`   Did you mean `ie.document.getElementsByClassName` ?

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams. Now i don't get anymore Error '424' . unfortunately, I couldn't retrieve any data, still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first to use more precise selectors. For the first button use:

```
ie.document.querySelector(".header__menu-services__nav").click
```

That targets the element by one of its classes. Then have a pause e.g.

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState<>4:DoEvents:Wend
```

Or, use an explicit wait time or loop until next desired element is present.

Then target the next element with [type selectors and child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) as you want the first child `button` within a `li` element:

```
ie.document.querySelector("li > button").click
```

Then you need another wait.

Finally, you can use a single class from the target elements, with the links, and extract the `href` attributes and store in an array (for example)

```
Dim nodes As Object, hrefs(), i As Long

Set nodes = ie.Document.querySelectorAll(".card-product")

ReDim hrefs(nodes.Length - 1)

For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
    hrefs(i) = nodes.Item(i).href
Next
```

---

EDIT:

Seems page uses ajax to retrieve the listings which makes this easier. I show to versions. The first where I grab just those links you describe after two button clicks; the second, where I grab model subtype links as well.

In both I mimic the request the page makes to get that info. In the first I then parse the returned json with a json parser and pull out the model links. With the second, I regex out all href info ie. all submodels.

---

**Json library:**

I use jsonconverter.bas. Download raw code from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and add to standard module called JsonConverter . You then need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Remove the top Attribute line from the copied code.

1)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ScrapeModelLinks1()
    
    Dim data As Object, links() As Variant, s As String
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.aprilia.com/en_EN/aprilia/en/index?ajax=true", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With

    Set data = JsonConverter.ParseJson(s)("pageData")("main")("component-06")("items")
    
    ReDim links(data.Count)
    Dim item As Long, base As String
    
    base = "https://www.aprilia.com"

    For item = 1 To data.Count
        links(item) = base & data(item)("href")
    Next
    
    Stop
    
End Sub
```

---

2. 

```
Public Sub ScrapeModelLinks2()
    'grab all href which will include model subtypes
    Dim s As String
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.aprilia.com/en_EN/aprilia/en/index?ajax=true", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim re As Object, matches As Object, links() As Variant
    
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    re.Pattern = """href"":""(.*?)"""
    re.Global = True
    Set matches = re.Execute(s)
    
    ReDim links(matches.Count - 1)
    Dim item As Long, base As String
    
    base = "https://www.aprilia.com"
 
    For item = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        links(item) = base & matches(item).submatches(0)
    Next
    
    Stop
    
End Sub
```

---

**Regex explanation:**

[image]

Comment: Hello @Harr, i tried to modify the code as you suggested. I get no error, but couldn't retrieve any data.

Comment: Did you inspect hrefs in the locals window?

Comment: you mean, on the original webpage? btw, i've posted the new code I've written, thanks to your suggestions.

Comment: I mean on the original webpage run my code and with the STOP keyword inserted after the `Next` - when the code halts execution at the STOP keyword, open the locals window and inspect the contents of the variable `hrefs` - Is it populated?

Comment: you're totally right. If i check the webpage using "STOP", there's no href data available. Again, thank you for taking the time to read this and consider it.

Comment: No href data stored in the variable or no href data on the webpage itself? Or both?

Comment: oh..... I have to wonder if there isn't a long enough pause earlier in the code then. Did you step through with F8 executing code line by line? Also, you need to close off your `On Error Resume Next` with `On Error GoTo 0` after the line you want to ignore errors on. So `On Error Resume Next`  < line of code to ignore errors for> `On Error GoTo 0` ; otherwise, you just keep ignoring errors throughout the rest of the program.

Comment: Again, thank you for your support. Checking with F8, i got an Error '13' - Type Mismatch when executing the line Set ELE = ie.document.querySelector(".header__menu-services__nav"). I really can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: you need to declare ELE as `Dim ELE As Object`. This `Dim ie, ELE, nodes As Object` declaration leaves you with the first two as implicit variants and the last as an object.

Comment: Thank you QHarr! Unfortunately, now I got an  Error '424' - Object Required. One more thing I noticed when stepping through with F8: the page opened in IE (because ie.visible = true) has no content. What i mean is: if i open it throught the browser, i can see all the buttons and videos. When i open it via VBA, it's an empty page, and the html code doesn't show any content. I'm afraid this is loaded by some javascript function. If  that's the case, do you think what i'm trying to achieve is still doable?

Comment: To view the object you need ie.Visible = True then ie.Navigate "url goes here"

Comment: Sorry, maybe my previous comment was unclear. I mean that when the webpage is loaded from VBA, if i click on "View Source" in the browser, there's no html content. And, after loading, i get Error '424' - Object required, when i try to quick the first button

Comment: Thank you very much QHarr! your code does exactly what i was expecting. For my education, from where have you detected that this webpage uses ajax to load the content?

Comment: I looked in the network tab Find xhr requests feeding dynamic content [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56279841/6241235), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924071/6241235), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61051360/6241235)