# Handling an element without click attribute

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to click this element called "Select File", it is a button but i am unable to click it using selenium command. The the element I am about to click is as follows:

```
<label for="file" class="pb default" style="display: inline-block;margin: 5px 10px;">Select File</label>
```

the script I am using to click for that element is:

```
_test_=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("pb default")
_test_.click()
```

It gives an exception like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:\test_selenium_impossible_click.py", line 58, in
<module>
    _test_.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I am using latest firefox version with latest webdriver for firefox

**UPDATE :**
i have edited the code to become like this :

```
_test_=browser.find_element_by_class_name("pb default")
_test_.click()
```

but now it gives output like this :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:\automator-python\test_selenium_impossible_click.py", line 57, in <module>
    _test_=browser.find_element_by_class_name("pb default")
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .pb default
```

i have tried the other ways like what has been suggested to me but it still gives output like what i mentioned above...do you know how to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not missing attributes, it in the element locating.

`find_elements_*` return a list, not a single element, so you can't click it.

`by_class_name` recive a single class as parameter, you sent two.

To locate the element by multiple classes use `css_selector`

```
find_element_by_css_selector('.pb.default')
```

Comment: hello, i have changed that according to your suggestion, but now the output for the code is like this :

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .pb default

do you know the solution for that? thx

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

...implies that *AttributeError* was raised when you tried to invoke `click()` on a *List* element.

---

[click()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click) method can be invoked only on a [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) but not on a *List*.

In your code trials you have used `find_elements_by_class_name()` (note the s in elements) which returns a *List*. So when you try to invoke `click()` on the *List*, **AttributeError** is raised. So first of all you need to replace `find_elements_by_class_name()` with **`find_element_by_class_name()`**.

Additionally, you can't pass multiple classes as arguments to `find_element_by_class_name()` which will result in [invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022) error. To pass multiple classes you have to use either [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) or [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as a [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  _test_ = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".pb.default")
  _test_.click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  _test_ = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='pb default']")
  _test_.click()
  ```

---

However, as per best practices, I would suggest to use a granular locator adding the `tag_name` as follows:

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  _test_ = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("label.pb.default[for='file']")
  _test_.click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  _test_ = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='pb default' and @for='file']")
  _test_.click()
  ```

---

### Update

Ideally, while invoking `click()` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.pb.default[for='file']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='pb default' and @for='file']"))).click()
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: hello, i have changed that according to your suggestion, but now the output for the code is like this :

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .pb default

do you know the solution for that? thx

Comment: @CybersAndroidz Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.