# Trying to get an element of a class using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I just start learning python. So on this chapter it's basically to a create a price tracker using selenium.

The photo below is what I'm trying to get using selenium.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh2K7.png)

if i try

`search_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a-price a-text-price a-size-medium apexPriceToPay")`

it shows red sea of lines , saying no buch Message: no such element

Then I try

`search_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a-offscreen")`

the output is: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e1349ab77fff9cc0f9c565cc173927d", element="bbd837af-3cdf-4bd1-825c-9fd8cd27f719")>

I'm really new to programming...so I tried using .text at the end, no luck!

what can i do to get the price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```py
search_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "apexPriceToPay")
```

Or maybe

```py
search_box = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".a-price.a-text-price")
```

To give a precise answer we need to see the entire page HTML to find the shortest unique locator

Comment: https://www.amazon.ca/Pure-Protein-Chocolate-100-Powder/dp/B00BMHB5WM/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=protein+powder&qid=1639291298&sr=8-10

forgive me for posting the whole amazon link. I don't really know where to begin

Comment: Thanks. I see that `apexPriceToPay` is a unique class name. So you can use `search_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "apexPriceToPay")`.  
BTW don't forget to accept the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things:

1. You can't pass multiple classnames within `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "classA classB classC classD")` as it may raise [*invalid selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022).
2. Passing the *classname* *`a-offscreen`* selects ***18*** elements, so you even can't use it.
3. You will see the output as:

   ```
   <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0e1349ab77fff9cc0f9c565cc173927d", element="bbd837af-3cdf-4bd1-825c-9fd8cd27f719")>
   ```

   when you will print the element itself, which you don't need either.

---

### Solution

To print the text *`$20.97`* you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[starts-with(., 'Price')]//following-sibling::td[1]/span[contains(@class, 'a-price')]/span[@aria-hidden='true']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *xpath*, the second `<span>` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[starts-with(., 'Price')]//following-sibling::td[1]/span[contains(@class, 'a-price')]/span[@aria-hidden='true']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  $20.97
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)