# How to copy tags in selenium when element contains multiple classnames?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Scraping data from a website in which a lot of text was hidden under the "see more" tab.

Via `selenium` click all such buttons and then scrape using `beautifulsoup`. However, a few of the buttons have extra whitespaces in their HTML tags. copying and pasting them to `browser.find_element_by_class_name('')` always yields an error.

```
 class="pv-profile-section__see-more-inline pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle
        artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--muted"
```

Notice how there's extra white space behind artdeco, could anyone help me with this please?
Manually adding those spaces or putting them in same line doesn't do anything.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ and __scraping__ not scrap or scrapping. To scrap, and scrapping, means to throw away like rubbish, or to fight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: *You won't be able to pass multiple classnames as argument through `find_element_by_class_name()` cause it only accept a single classname*

To find element by multiple classnames try to use [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".firstClassName.secondClassName")
```

Answer (score 1):

As *@HedgeHog* mentioned in the answer, you won't be able to pass multiple classnames within

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "classA classB classC classD")
```

as it may raise [*invalid selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022).

---

Moreover as you find multiple classnames *`pv-profile-section__see-more-inline`*, *`pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle`*, *`artdeco-button--tertiary`*, etc with extra whitespaces an ideal approach would be to consider a unique classname e.g. ***pv-profile-section__see-more-inline*** which appears unique to functionality of the given element, i.e. <kbd>see more</kbd> and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `class_name`:

  ```
  browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "classname")
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.pv-profile-section__see-more-inline")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "input[@class='pv-profile-section__see-more-inline']")
  ```