# SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal within XPath using Selenium and ChromeDriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to gather recent NFT transaction activity from an OpenSea profile. I am getting a SyntaxError for some reason and I cannot figure out what is causing the error. I have triple checked all of my code and am lost on where the error is coming from. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am on MacOS.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = ('/Users/Chris/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://opensea.io/GaryVee")
action = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Flexreact__Flex-sc-1twd32i-0 ''''FlexColumnreact__FlexColumn-sc-1wwz3hp-0 eaQZLu jYqxGr ksFzlZ')

for action in action:
    nft_name = action.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[''1]/button/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span[1]/div/div/a').text
    nft_id = action.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[''1]/button/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span[2]/a/div').text
    price_eth = action.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[''1]/button/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/text()').text
    price_usd = action.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[''1]/button/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/span/div/div').text
    sending_user = action.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[''1]/button/div/div[5]/div/a/span').text
    recieving_user = action.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[''2]/div[1]/button/div/div[6]/div/a/span').text
    status = action.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[''1]/button/div/div[1]/h6')
```

And this is my error code:

```
  File "/Users/Chris /PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 28
        status = action.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[''1]/button/div/div[1]/h6')
                                                                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the triple quotes within the *`CLASS_NAME`* was unnecessary or a typo. However, [you can't pass multiple classnames through `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'classname')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022).

To identify the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  action = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0.Flexreact__Flex-sc-1twd32i-0.FlexColumnreact__FlexColumn-sc-1wwz3hp-0.OpenSeaPagereact__DivContainer-sc-65pnmt-0.dBFmez.jYqxGr.ksFzlZ.iRiGb")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  action = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Flexreact__Flex-sc-1twd32i-0 FlexColumnreact__FlexColumn-sc-1wwz3hp-0 OpenSeaPagereact__DivContainer-sc-65pnmt-0 dBFmez jYqxGr ksFzlZ iRiGb']")
  ```

Comment: The two single quotes aren't actually an error (though they are unnecessary, they don't hurt anything).

Comment: @kindall agreed. The error was somewhere else, corrected now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `''''` in this line:

```
action = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Flexreact__Flex-sc-1twd32i-0 ''''FlexColumnreact__FlexColumn-sc-1wwz3hp-0 eaQZLu jYqxGr ksFzlZ')
```

This closes your initial string literal (which began with `'`) and starts a new string literal (which begins with `'''`). You never close this second string literal, so the rest of your code is a string, and Python complains it got to the end of the program without you ever closing the string.

I don't have any idea what you're trying to do with the four apostrophes in a row so I can't tell you how to fix it, but that's the problem.

Comment: _CLASS_NAME_ with _`blank`_ characters ??

Comment: what "blank characters" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

```
action = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Flexreact__Flex-sc-1twd32i-0 ''''FlexColumnreact__FlexColumn-sc-1wwz3hp-0 eaQZLu jYqxGr ksFzlZ')
```

That line of code contains a triple quote, which is never terminated.

Triple quotes are special in Python.