# Finding an element on website using Selenium for Python that has newlines inside its class name

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data from LinkedIn but I noticed that the elements id change each time I load the page with Selenium. So I tried using class name to find all the elements but the class names have newline inside of them, preventing me from scraping the website.

[example of class with newlines here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUprw.png)

[Website link example](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3425809260&keywords=python)

I tried doing the below:

```
job_test = "ember-view   jobs-search-results__list-item occludable-update p0 relative scaffold-layout__list-item\n              \n              \n              "

job_list = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, job_test)
```

I even tried this:

```
job_test = '''ember-view   jobs-search-results__list-item occludable-update p0 relative scaffold-layout__list-item
              
              
              '''
job_list = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, job_test)
```

But it does not show me any elements when I print job_list. What do I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*`By.CLASS_NAME`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#selenium.webdriver.common.by.By.CLASS_NAME) accepts only one classname, so you can't pass multiple. See: [Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted error using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536022/7429447)

---

### Solution

To create the job list you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CLASS_NAME*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3425809260&keywords=python')
  job_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "jobs-search-results__list-item")))
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3425809260&keywords=python')
  job_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.jobs-search-results__list-item")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3425809260&keywords=python')
  job_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class, 'jobs-search-results__list-item')]")))
  ```