# Selenium can't find element even it's located on the screen

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Here is the sample HTML test.html:

```
<html>
<div class="h1 mb-4 font-weight-normal nh-read__title"> Test Title </div>
<html>
```

I tried to get the `<div>` by selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file://test.html")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "h1 mb-4 font-weight-normal nh-read__title"))
)
```

The page loads instantly, however after 10 seconds, it raises a `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` error.
I'm not sure what's wrong here since I can get any other element with this code (get by id, ...). I want to get the above `<div>` by class name only.

The version of chromedriver and python I'm using is 111 and 3.10.

Comment: You can't pass multiple classes in that selector. [See this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536022/21146235) for discussion and possibilities.

Comment: @moto Oh I got it. Thank you so much!. Can you post this comment as an answer so I can mark the question as solved?

Comment: Glad it helped! Prefer not to duplicate existing answers so you get this one for free :-)