# How to locate an element with multiple classnames using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, classname

I'm trying to click on the following element with the class name equals `"clean right"`:

```
<li class="clean right"></li>
```

How could I locate it by using `driver.find_element_by_class_name()`

Comment: it must be 'clean.right'

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Compound class names not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771604/selenium-compound-class-names-not-permitted)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass multiple classnames as argument through `find_element_by_class_name()` and doing so you will face an error as:

```
invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

---

There are multiple approaches to solve this usecase and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- If the element is uniquely identified only through the `classname` **`clean`** you can use:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_class_name("clean")
  ```
- If the element is uniquely identified only through the `classname` **`right`** you can use:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_class_name("right")
  ```
- If both the `classnames`, **`clean`** and **`right`** are mandatory to identify the element, you can use [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) as follows:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.clean.right")
  ```
- As an alternative you can also use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='clean right']")
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted error using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022)

---

### Reference

[Find div element by multiple class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names/60515585#60515585)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is partially incorrect. please check the source code at :

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/9160de55af9cc230f758f4ce6a2af8d1570f0614/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py

You can use class_name for multiple classes , just need to replace space with '.'

Example for using class with space:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")
sleep(5)
#browser.refresh()
elem=browser.find_element_by_class_name('RP4i1.UVauz')
print(elem.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
browser.get_screenshot_as_file(f"screenshot.png")
```

**Output:**

```
<img class="RP4i1  UVauz" src="/static/images/homepage/screenshot1.jpg/d6bf0c928b5a.jpg" alt="">
```

If you check the exception from the by_class_name:

[image]

You can see that it is using css_class locator under the hood ( You can see it add . in frontautomatically)

**Another Working example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579491/find-element-by-class-name-in-selenium-giving-error/65579606?noredirect=1#comment115946541_65579606")
time.sleep(5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('overflow-x-auto.ml-auto.-secondary.grid.ai-center.list-reset.h100')

print(elem.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

Comment: I'm forced to downvote this answer as this answer is conceptually wrong. You are completely messing up the concept of locators.

Comment: @DebanjanB could you explain why ?

Comment: @DebanjanB in what level do you think the answer is wrong ?

Comment: THe answer provides a working example also

Comment: by_class_name just adds '.' infront of the locator provided so  'a' will be passed as .a and a.b will be passed as '.a.b'

Comment: That is the equalent of finding multiple class by css locator

Comment: _could you explain why_: The top most discussion from Frequently viewed question of Selenium will give you a crystal clear picture what happens under the hood. However that discussion is also linked within my answer for this discussion. Let me know if you still have any doubts.

Comment: @DebanjanB You are referrring to your own answers which are incorrect ,

Comment: COuld you mention why do you think its not conceptually correct ?

Comment: The exception it self mention that it uses css selector @DebanjanB and it shows it uses css class selector .class

Comment: @DebanjanB your answer is correct for java

Comment: The WebDriver specifications are identically implemented through Selenium's _java_ and _python_ client. If you observe any discrepancies between their implementation feel free to raise a bug in the SeleniumHQ queue. I will be happy to look into that.

Comment: in java it is adding .overflow\-x\-auto\.ml\-auto a front slash to the '.'

Comment: What is stopping you from referring to the client code _java_ or _python_?

Comment: @DebanjanB   elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:
                by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
                value = ".%s" % value   this is python code in hood just replacing with .%s and css locator

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/9160de55af9cc230f758f4ce6a2af8d1570f0614/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py

Comment: You are looking at the right place but your interpretation is wrong. In short it's **`By.CLASS_NAME`** not `By.CLASS_NAMES`

Comment: @DebanjanB where did we mention CLASS_NAMES ? can we use the method for finding multiple class "Answer is yes"

Comment: Your answer says You can't pass multiple classnames as argument through find_element_by_class_name() and doing so you will face an error as: whioch is incorrect . Could you revert the downvote