# How to find the class path for the number of recovered people from covid using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, classname

So, I need to get the text (number of recovered people from covid) from this webpage into the console, but I can't find the class for the numbers can someone help me to locate the class, so I can print the numbers into the console. I need to use PhantomJS cuz I don't want the log to open when I run the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.tvnet.lv/covid19Live')

text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("covid-summary__count covid-c-recovered")
print(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

`find_element_by_class_name()` expects a *single class* as an argument but you are providing two class names (class is a *"multi-valued attribute"*, multiple values are separated by a space).

Either check for a single class:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("covid-c-recovered")
```

Or, switch to a CSS selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".covid-summary__count.covid-c-recovered")
```

---

#### Digging Deeper

Let's look at the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/0e0194b0e52a34e7df4b841f1ed74506beea5c3e/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#L727-L729). When elements are searched by class name, Python selenium actually constructs a CSS selector under the hood:

```
elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:
    by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    value = ".%s" % value
```

This means that when you've used `covid-summary__count covid-c-recovered` as a class name value, the actual CSS selector that was used to find an element happened to be:

```
.covid-summary__count covid-c-recovered
```

which understandably did not match any elements (`covid-c-recovered` would be considered as a tag name here).

Comment: It gives me an error: Screenshot: available via screen

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number make sure you have dots between class names.

```
driver.get('https://www.tvnet.lv/covid19Live')
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("covid-summary__count.covid-c-recovered")
print(element.text)
```

Outputs

```
19 072
```

Comment: It gives me an error: Screenshot: available via screen

Answer (score 0):

From per the documentation of [selenium.webdriver.common.by](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) implementation:

```
class selenium.webdriver.common.by.By
    Set of supported locator strategies.

    CLASS_NAME = 'class name'
```

So using `find_element_by_class_name()` you won't be able to pass multiple class names as it accepts a single class.

---

### Solution

To print the number of people **HEALED** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *LATVIJĀ*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[contains(., 'COVID-19 LATVIJĀ')]//following::ul[1]//p[@class='covid-summary__count covid-c-recovered']").text)
  ```
- *PASAULĒ*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[contains(., 'COVID-19 PASAULĒ')]//following::ul[1]//p[@class='covid-summary__count covid-c-recovered']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *LATVIJĀ*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tvnet.lv/covid19Live")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[contains(., 'COVID-19 LATVIJĀ')]//following::ul[1]//p[@class='covid-summary__count covid-c-recovered']"))).text)
  ```
- *PASAULĒ*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tvnet.lv/covid19Live")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[contains(., 'COVID-19 PASAULĒ')]//following::ul[1]//p[@class='covid-summary__count covid-c-recovered']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  19 072
  52 546 925
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted error using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022)
- [How to locate an element with multiple class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534244/how-to-locate-an-element-with-multiple-class-names/60534315#60534315)

Comment: it still gives me the same error (selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Screenshot: available via screen)

Comment: It gives me an error: (selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Screenshot: available via screen)

Comment: @Lagis_YTYT There was a minor bug, corrected it. Please retest.