# driver.find_element_by_class_name() but the class name has spaces

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, classname, class-names

```
Error message : selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression ". clickable event-link math " is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: Document.querySelector: '. clickable event-link math ' is not a valid selector: ". clickable event-link math "
```

My guess is due to the spaces cause I saw similar issues with spaces but couldn't find a solution that worked for me

```
Algebra = ' clickable event-link math '
math = driver.find_element_by_class_name(Algebra)
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that element has several classes... Try to use CSS-selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".clickable.event-link.math")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [**`selenium.webdriver.common.by`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) implementation:

```
class selenium.webdriver.common.by.By
    Set of supported locator strategies.

    CLASS_NAME = 'class name'
```

So,

- Using `find_element_by_class_name()` you won't be able to pass multiple class names.
  Passing multiple classes you will face the error as:

  ```
    Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  ```
- Additionally, as you want to return an array of the chats, so instead of `find_element*` you need to use **`find_elements*`**

---

### Solution

As an alternative you can use either of :the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
    math = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".clickable.event-link math")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
    math = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'clickable') and contains(@class, 'event-link math')]")
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted error using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528072/invalid-selector-compound-class-names-not-permitted-error-using-selenium/53536022#53536022)
- [How to locate an element with multiple class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60534244/how-to-locate-an-element-with-multiple-class-names/60534315#60534315)